# Journals of the early 20th century

Tags: physics, publishing, resource-recommendation

Which journals were the most commonly used journals for the publication of research papers in physics in the late 19th century and the early 20th century, specifically from 1875 to 1925?

Comment: This question is easily answered by looking to Wikipedia articles like Max Planck, Albert Einstein, Werner Heisenberg, Marie Curie etc.

Comment: You might also take [this list](https://www.zentralblatt-math.org/JFM/publications/find?what=title&type=complete&keyword=phys) of (currently) 197 journals over 1868-1930, then count reviewed papers in any of them by using its title as "source" in [JFM search](https://www.emis.de/MATH/JFM/full.html).